# What are the possible ways to visualise large, entangled states?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-state

What are the prominent visualizations used to depict large, entangled states and in what context are they most commonly applied?

What are their advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 4):

In [Verifying Genuine High-Order Entanglement](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/49751841_Verifying_Genuine_High-Order_Entanglement?_sg=EMjw2Jt54efwaihq3BCmAnkPUnwDg7x075lZmU-0x5tjFm1J9bXMWMx1CPI2ooEh6ir6OPcZrg) the following graphs represent entangled qudits

[image: 10-qudit state]
[image: qudit graph states]

---

In [an answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1641/2645) to 'Alternative to Bloch sphere to represent a single qubit' @Rob references [Majorana representation, qutrit Hilbert space and NMR implementation of qutrit gates](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06102) which states

> The Majorana representation for spin−$s$ systems has found widespread applications such as determining geometric phase of spins, representing $N$ spinors by $N$ points, geometrical representation of multi-qubit entangled states, statistics of chaotic quantum dynamical systems and characterizing polarized light.

The paper also includes this style of representation for qudits

[image: majorana representation]

---

I recently asked about how to [visually represent a qubyte](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/how-to-represent-a-qubyte). In the comments of @DaftWullie's answer I proposed an 8-cube ([hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Graphs)):

[image: 8-cube]

> An n-cube can be projected inside a regular 2n-gonal polygon by a skew orthogonal projection

This method seems to allow for the [complexity](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/13-cube.svg) of entanglement to be visualized in a scalable fashion.

Comment: Why on earth did someone downvote? I upvoted to neutralize it.

Comment: I upvoted you. I share your pain

Comment: These pictures are completely uninformative.  What do they visualize, and how?

Answer (score 4):

The ZX-calculus is a graphical language for dealing with linear maps of qubits, and it can in particular represent any state of qubits. Basically, ZX-diagrams are tensor networks, but there is an additional set of rewrite rules that allows you to manipulate them graphically. On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX-calculus#Diagram_rewriting) you can find an example of how to prove that a certain quantum circuit indeed implements a GHZ-state. [It has also been used](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6242) to reason about Measurement-Based Quantum Computing, because it allows you to straightforwardly reason about graph states.

In [PyZX](https://github.com/Quantomatic/pyzx) (disclaimer: I am a lead developer) we use automated graph rewriting to reason and prove results with ZX-diagrams involving thousands of vertices, and we can visualize circuits and states on dozens of qubits.

Answer (score 2):

My personal view:

Yes, large entangled states can be visualized using quantum bayesian networks. See

- [Factorization of Quantum Density Matrices According to Bayesian and Markov Networks, by Robert R. Tucci](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0701201) (obviously I am the author here)
- [Python tools for analyzing both classical and quantum Bayesian Networks](https://github.com/artiste-qb-net/quantum-fog) (Disclaimer: artiste-qb.net is my company)

Other people will probably advise using Tensor Networks instead of quantum Bayesian nets. This begs the question: How do Quantum Bayesian Networks and Tensor Networks compare? I have thought about that and gathered my thoughts in [this](https://qbnets.wordpress.com/2015/03/26/tensor-networks-versus-quantum-bayesian-networks-and-the-winner-is/) blog post.

First lines of blog post:

> A question I am often asked is what is the difference between tensor
>   networks and quantum Bayesian networks, and is there any advantage to
>   using one over the other.
>
> When dealing with probabilities, I prefer quantum Bayesian networks
>   because b nets are a more natural way of expressing probabilities (and
>   probability amplitudes) whereas tensor nets can be used to denote many
>   physical quantities other than probabilities so they are not tailor
>   made for the job as b nets are. Let me explain in more detail for the
>   technically inclined.

One can consider bipartite entanglement for the two sides of a partition, of a quantum bayesian network. One can write nice inequalities for such bipartite entanglements. See, for example, [Entanglement Polygon Inequality in Qubit Systems,
Xiao-Feng Qian, Miguel A. Alonso, Joseph H. Eberly](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08415).

One can also try to define a measure of n-partite entanglement for n>2, where n is the number of nodes of a quantum Bayesian net.
See, for example, [Verifying Genuine High-Order Entanglement, Che-Ming Li, Kai Chen, Andreas Reingruber, Yueh-Nan Chen, Jian-Wei Pan](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5012).